# Strip down webpage to just text on iOS (Objective C)

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My main goal here is to achieve an effect like Readability or Safari's Reader service where the main content of the webpage is converted to text. I don't actually want to display any images, just get all the webpage's important text. I am currently using some pretty long self-built code to parse the webpage for the s to find out what the heading may look like, and I am also parsing the

s that I hope contain the majority of the page's content.

```
-(void)interpretAndDisplay {
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.url];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];

//Getting the H1s
NSMutableArray *h1Full = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
h1Full = [self stringsBetweenString:@"<h1" andString:@">" andText:html];

if ([h1Full count] > 0) {
    NSMutableArray *h1Content = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    h1Content = [self stringsBetweenString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<h1%@>",[h1Full firstObject]] andString:@"</h1>" andText:html];
    NSMutableArray *h1Sanitize = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    h1Sanitize = [self stringsBetweenString:@"<" andString:@">" andText:html];

    if ([h1Content count] > 0) {
        NSString *finalTitle = [h1Content firstObject];

        for (int i = 0; i < [h1Sanitize count]; i++) {
            NSString *toRemove = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",[h1Sanitize objectAtIndex:i]];
            finalTitle = [finalTitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:toRemove withString:@""];
            finalTitle = [finalTitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

        }

        finalTitle = [self sanitizeString:finalTitle];

        [self.titleLabel setText:finalTitle];
    }

}

//Now for the body!
NSMutableArray *pTag = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
pTag = [self stringsBetweenString:@"<p" andString:@">" andText:html];
if ([pTag count] > 0) {
    NSMutableArray *pContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    pContent = [self stringsBetweenString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p%@>",[pTag firstObject]] andString:@"</p>" andText:html];

    NSMutableArray *pSanitize = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    pSanitize = [self stringsBetweenString:@"<" andString:@">" andText:html];

    if ([pContent count] > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < [pContent count]; i++) {
            NSString *pToEdit = [pContent objectAtIndex:i];

            for (int i = 0; i < [pSanitize count]; i++) {
                NSString *toRemove = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",[pSanitize objectAtIndex:i]];
                pToEdit = [pToEdit stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:toRemove withString:@""];
            }

            [pContent replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:pToEdit];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < [pContent count]; i++) {
            NSString *pToEdit = [pContent objectAtIndex:i];
            pToEdit = [pToEdit stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
            [pContent replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:pToEdit];
        }

        NSString *finalBody = @"";

        for (int i = 0; i < [pContent count]; i++) {

            if ([finalBody isEqualToString:@""]) {
                finalBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[pContent objectAtIndex:i]];
            }

            else {
                finalBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@",finalBody,[pContent objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }

        finalBody = [self sanitizeString:finalBody];

        [self.textLabel setText:finalBody];
    }

}
}
```

The above code extracts all of the elements just fine and sanitizes them with a method that I created, but the problem is that just analyzing the P tags sometimes completely fails to simplify the content, and analyzing all possible content tags could mess with the content's order and layout.

Is there a better way or some framework that converts all the text into a nice string?

**EDIT**

Searching around, I found a Boilerpipe project that can extract text extremely easily (https://github.com/k-bx/boilerpipe/wiki/QuickStart). It looks as easy as this: `String text= ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);`

Can I do this on Objective C?

**Edit 2**

It appears that there is a boilerpipe API, but this has limited requests. I am mostly looking for a user-side solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reggie is not the most tolerant approach in my opinion.

I'd try to find an existent open source (i.e. https://github.com/Kerrick/readability-js) and use [WebKit](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/) to inject JS into a web page once loaded.

After that you can inject another JS, extracting the processed content (using the [appropriate class from the source](https://github.com/Kerrick/readability-js/blob/develop/readability.js#L113))

Then, using [JavaScriptCore](http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/) you can pass `div`'s content to Objective-C (JS offers many ways of doing that)

Comment: I understand the basic concept of this, but are there any tutorials that explain how this process works?

Comment: Have you checked the links I provided? they go over the basics with code samples in objective-c and swift